# React Typescript Tag drag to text area

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I'm using my react typescript project for  **[Ant design,](https://ant.design/components/tag/)** I'm find some tutorial for this but any one not see,

this is my conflict, I wanna tag dragging to text area,  so when I type the text and then drag tag next type text and dragging tag,

[image]
anyone know solution?

**[stazkblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu?file=index.js)**

Thanks

**code here**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Comment, Avatar, Form, Button, List, Input,Tag } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';

const { TextArea } = Input;

const CommentList = ({ comments }) => (
  <List
    dataSource={comments}
    header={`${comments.length} ${comments.length > 1 ? 'replies' : 'reply'}`}
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    renderItem={props => <Comment {...props} />}
  />
);

const Editor = ({ onChange, onSubmit, submitting, value }) => (
  <>
    <Form.Item>
      <TextArea rows={4} onChange={onChange} value={value} />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit" loading={submitting} onClick={onSubmit} type="primary">
        Add Comment
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments: [],
    submitting: false,
    value: '',
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!this.state.value) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      submitting: true,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        submitting: false,
        value: '',
        comments: [
          ...this.state.comments,
          {
            author: 'Han Solo',
            avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
            content: <p>{this.state.value}</p>,
            datetime: moment().fromNow(),
          },
        ],
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { comments, submitting, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <>

       <div>
      <Tag color="magenta">magenta</Tag>
      <Tag color="red">red</Tag>
      <Tag color="volcano">volcano</Tag>
      <Tag color="orange">orange</Tag>
      <Tag color="gold">gold</Tag>
      <Tag color="lime">lime</Tag>
      <Tag color="green">green</Tag>
      <Tag color="cyan">cyan</Tag>
      <Tag color="blue">blue</Tag>
      <Tag color="geekblue">geekblue</Tag>
      <Tag color="purple">purple</Tag>
    </div>
        {comments.length > 0 && <CommentList comments={comments} />}
        <Comment
          avatar={
            <Avatar
              src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"
              alt="Han Solo"
            />
          }
          content={
            <Editor
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              submitting={submitting}
              value={value}
            />
          }
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Do you want to drag and drop the "Tag" to "Textarea"? If yes, you need to implement [drag and drop](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp).

Comment: @AjeetShah  yes, but wanna like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z6an.png, when i type my name is <Tag> drop to text area

Answer (score 0):

There must be a simpler way doing it, the below can be one of the methods solving it.
Hope helps

```
> import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
> import'antd/dist/antd.css'; import './index.css'; 
> import { Comment, Avatar,Form, Button, List, Input, Tag, Typography 
> }from 'antd'; import
> moment from 'moment'; const { Title, Paragraph, Text, Link } =
> Typography; const { TextArea } = Input;
> 
> const CommentList = ({ comments }) => (   <List
>     dataSource={comments}
>     header={`${comments.length} ${comments.length > 1 ? 'replies' : 
> 'reply'}`}
>     itemLayout="horizontal"
>     renderItem={props => <Comment {...props} />}   /> );
> 
> const Editor = ({ onChange, onSubmit, submitting, value }) => (   <>
>     <Form.Item>
>       <TextArea rows={4} onChange={onChange} value={value} />
>     </Form.Item>
>     <Form.Item>
>       <Button htmlType="submit" loading={submitting} onClick={onSubmit} 
> type="primary">
>         Add Comment
>       </Button>
>     </Form.Item>   </> );
> 
> class App extends React.Component {   state = {
>     comments: [],
>     submitting: false,
>     value: '',   };
> 
>   handleSubmit = () => {
>     if (!this.state.value) {
>       return;
>     }
>     const inputValue = this.state.value
> 
>     const inputValueArr = inputValue.split('')
>     let result = []
>     let stack = [], temp = [], flag = true, tagValue = []
>     for(let index in inputValueArr) {
>       if(inputValueArr[index] === '<') {
>         stack.push(inputValueArr[index])
>         flag = false
>       }else if(!flag) {
>         if(inputValueArr[index] !== '>') {
>           tagValue.push(inputValueArr[index])
>         }
>       
>         if(stack.length === 1 && inputValueArr[index] === '>') {
>           const beforeValue = temp.join('')
>           result.push({text: beforeValue, isTag: false})
>           const tagText = tagValue.join('')
>           result.push({text: tagText, isTag: true})
>           flag = true
>           stack.pop()
>         }
>       }else if(flag){
>         temp.push(inputValueArr[index])
>       }
>     }
> 
>     if(result.length === 0) {
>       const textValue = temp.join('')
>       result.push({text: textValue, isTag: false})
>     }
>     this.setState({
>       submitting: true,
>     });
> 
>     setTimeout(() => {
>       this.setState({
>         submitting: false,
>         value: '',
>         comments: [
>           ...this.state.comments,
>           {
>             author: 'Han Solo',
>             avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
>             content: result.map((item, index) => {
>               if(item.isTag) {
>                 return this.generateComment(item.text, item.isTag)
>               }else {
>                 return this.generateComment(item.text, item.isTag)
>               }
>                
>             }) ,
>             datetime: moment().fromNow(),
>           },
>         ],
>       });
>     }, 1);   };   generateComment = (text, isTag) => {
>     if(isTag) {
>       return <Tag>{text}</Tag>
>     }else {
>       return text
>     }   }   generateComments = (result) => {
>     console.log(result)
>     return (
>       <Paragraph>
>         {result.map((item, index) => {
>           if(item.isTag) {
>             return (
> 
>                 <Text code key={item.text+index}>{item.text}</Text>
> 
>               )
>           }else {
>             return <p key={item.text+index}>{item.text}</p>
>           }
>           
>         })}
>       </Paragraph>
>     )   }   handleChange = e => {
>     this.setState({
>       value: e.target.value,
>     });   };
> 
>   render() {
>     const { comments, submitting, value } = this.state;
> 
>     return (
>       <>
>         {comments.length > 0 && <CommentList comments={comments} />}
>         <Comment
>           avatar={
>             <Avatar
>               src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"
>               alt="Han Solo"
>             />
>           }
>           content={
>             <Editor
>               onChange={this.handleChange}
>               onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
>               submitting={submitting}
>               value={value}
>             />
>           }
>         />
>       </>
>     );   } }
> 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```